# Filter an array using Angular filter

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of object i want to filter by Sensor Label, using angular `$filter`

```
SensorPort: [0: {Port: "1"SensorLabel: "Temperature"},1: {Port: "2"SensorLabel: ""},2: {Port: "3"SensorLabel: ""}]
```

Comment: please elaborate, what do you mean by 'filter by Sensor label'? Also, your json seems wrong.

Comment: rtm ? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, what you want to achieve. Consider your data:

```
 var sensorPortData = [{Port: "1", SensorLabel: "Temperature"},
         {Port: "2", SensorLabel: "Attempt"},
         {Port: "3", SensorLabel: "Nothing"}];
```

Then doing this, will give you:

```
 var searchQuery = "Tem";
 $filter('filter')(myData, {$: searchQuery}) == [{Port: "1", SensorLabel: "Temperature"},
        {Port: "2", SensorLabel: "Attempt"}]
```